# How to process raw jpeg data into a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, frontend, google-picker, raw-data

I'm trying to create a jpeg file from raw data in javascript

I've been using the google file picker api to allow users to select their images from drive and import into my application, but when I make the request to download the image google responds with raw data that looks like this:

[Google's response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6rZu.png)

I have tried placing that data into a blob with:

```
var blob = new Blob([res.text], {type: 'image/jpeg'})
```

I have also tried placing the data into a file.

```
var file = new File([res.text], 'image.jpeg', {type:"image/jpeg"})
```

However the file only renders black pixels. How can I go about generating a jpeg file from that data so I can upload to my server?

**Update(Solution):**
I switched my request api to fetch and used .blob() on the response

Comment: The image you attached is stream data of the JPEG file. Can you elaborate more about your expected answer

Comment: I agree that the image you attached looks like the JPEG data. My guess is this has to do with either the MimeType or the file extension. Are you specifying a filename with a (gif | jpg | png) extension?

Comment: I'm attempting to have that data into a file instance, of .jpeg extension. I'm not sure how to convert the data into the file

Comment: What API are you getting the `res` var from? don't use `.text` on it there should be a `.blob()` or somthing.

Comment: I'm using superagent, I'll try switching

Comment: .blob() solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For superagent see http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#parsing-response-bodies -> Binary and http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#response-properties -> Response body.

You need to use `.responseType('blob')` and `res.body`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-so-how-to-process-raw-jpeg-data-into-a-file-in-javascript